# How to remove a list of columns from pydatatable dataframe?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I have a datatable Frame created as:

```
comidas_gen_dt = dt.Frame({
    'country':list('ABCDE'),
    'id':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'egg':[10,20,30,5,40],
    'veg':[30,40,10,3,5],
    'fork':[5,10,2,1,9],
    'beef':[90,50,20,None,4]})
```

I have created a custom function to select a list of required columns from a frame `DT` as,

```
def pydt_select_cols(DT, *rmcols):
    return DT[:, *dt_cols]
```

So, here is the recommend syntax to remove columns from DT:

```
DT[:, f[:].remove([f.a, f.b, f.c])
```

following the above syntax of DT, I've create another custom function to keep a side a list of columns as

```
def pydt_remove_cols(DT, *rmcols):
    dt_cols = [*rmcols]
    return DT[:, f[:].remove(dt_cols)]
```

I'm executing the function as

```py
pydt_remove_cols(comidas_gen_dt, 'id', 'country', 'egg')
```

and it's throwing the error

> TypeError: Computed columns cannot be used in `.remove()`

Could you please help me how to go ahead with it?

Comment: Try [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: Nope it won’t work out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing columns (or rows) from a Frame is easy: take any syntax that you would normally use to select those columns, and then append the python `del` keyword.

Thus, if you want to delete columns `'id'`, `'country'`, and `'egg'`, run

```
>>> del comidas_gen_dt[:, ['id','country','egg']]
>>> comidas_gen_dt
   | veg  fork  beef
-- + ---  ----  ----
 0 |  30     5    90
 1 |  40    10    50
 2 |  10     2    20
 3 |   3     1    NA
 4 |   5     9     4

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

If you want to keep the original frame unmodified, and then select a new frame with some of the columns removed, then the easiest way would be to first copy the frame, and then use the `del` operation:

```
>>> DT = comidas_gen_dt.copy()
>>> del DT[:, columns_to_remove]
```

(note that `.copy()` makes a shallow copy, i.e. its cost is typically negligible).

You can also use the `f[:].remove()` approach. It's a bit strange that it didn't work the way you've written it, but going from a list of strings to a list of `f`-symbols is quite straightforward:

```
def pydt_remove_cols(DT, *rmcols):
    return DT[:, f[:].remove([f[col] for col in rmcols])]
```

Here I use the fact that `f.A` is the same as `f["A"]`, where the inner string `"A"` might as well be replaced with any variable.

Comment: Yes I’m aware of first approach, I have got a full clarification on using .remove on multiple columns. Thanks again for your quick responses